# NextAuth.js signIn() method not working using serverless-http in AWS Lambda

Tags: next.js, aws-serverless, next-auth

I am trying to deploy NextJs and NextAuth.js to AWS using CDK (Cloud Development Kit). I have cloned the NextAuth.js example project (https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example) and
installed "serverless-http" for handling the binding from Lambda to NextJs. I attempted to follow this guide https://remaster.com/blog/nextjs-lambda-serverless-framework but using AWS CDK instead of the serverless.yml file as I am integrating it with existing infrastructure.

next.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true
  },
  output: 'standalone'
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

[...nextauth].ts (From the example but using a simple credentials provider that always resolves):

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        return { id: "1", name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }
      }
    })
    
  ],
  theme: {
    colorScheme: "light",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token }) {
      token.userRole = "admin"
      return token
    },
  },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

server.ts:

```
import { NextConfig } from "next";
import NextServer from "next/dist/server/next-server";
import serverless from "serverless-http";
// @ts-ignore
import { config } from "./.next/required-server-files.json";

const nextServer = new NextServer({
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
    dir: __dirname,
    dev: false,
    conf: {
        ...(config as NextConfig),
    },
});

export const handler = serverless(nextServer.getRequestHandler());
```

It is being built using the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BUILD_FOLDER=.dist

yarn build
rm -rf $BUILD_FOLDER
mv .next/standalone/ $BUILD_FOLDER/
cp -r .next/static $BUILD_FOLDER/.next
rm $BUILD_FOLDER/server.js
cp -r next.config.js $BUILD_FOLDER/
cp -r node_modules/serverless-http $BUILD_FOLDER/node_modules/serverless-http
tsc server.ts --outDir .dist --esModuleInterop true
cp -r public $BUILD_FOLDER/
```

This is deployed using AWS written in CDK C#. Primarily using a HttpApi and a single Lambda. Each configured as shown below:

Lambda:

```cs
var function = new Function(this, "nextjs-function", new FunctionProps
{
    Code = Code.FromAsset(...".dist"),
    Handler = "server.handler",
    Runtime = Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
    ...
    Environment = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "NEXTAUTH_URL", "https://myDomainName.com" },
        { "NEXTAUTH_SECRET", portalSecret },
    }
});
```

HttpApi:

```cs
var httpApi = new HttpApi(this, "http-api", new HttpApiProps
{
    DisableExecuteApiEndpoint = true,
    DefaultIntegration = new HttpLambdaIntegration("nextjs-route", function),
    DefaultDomainMapping = new DomainMappingOptions
    {
        DomainName = "myDomainName.com"
    }
});
```

Opening the deployed webpage and clicking the "Sign In" button at the top, I get taken to /api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=%2F with a form. Without touching the credentials I click "Sign in with credentials". This results in the page reloading and nothing happening. Expected behaviour should be a session and a redirect back to the home page (/) as is happening when running it locally using either `yarn dev` or `yarn build && yarn start`.

I get no errors client/server-side thus leaving me in the dark.

I suspect that it has to do with domain configuration but I am unable to find the problem. I tested with another NextJs/NextAuth project using a AWS Cognito provider. This also had problems as when I clicked the sign in button I got an "Unexpected token" error due to the underlying signIn(...) function (from the NextAuth library) trying to parse the fetched page as JSON, which turned out to be the sign-in-page. Thus my suspicion of something domain-related.

Comment: same issue... are you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @AlbertOclarit I have yet to solve the problem. I went back to using an EC2 instance. However it seems other people have found a solution https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6435 (Post also by me)